# Trigonometric Proof for $(\sin x)^2$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that 
$$(\sin x)^2 = \left(\sin {\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2 - \left(\sin {\frac{x}{2}}\right)\left(\sin \left({\frac{x}{2}-2x}\right)\right).$$

Comment: Do you know the angle formulas for $\sin x$? For example, what is the formula for $\sin {(x-y)}$? Seems like that would be useful, along with the half and double angle formulas. Also looking for common factors.

Comment: The right side can be rewritten to $(\sin {\frac{x}{2}})^2 - (\sin {\frac{x}{2}})^2(\cos {2x}) + (\sin x)^2(\cos x)$ through $\sin ({a-b})$, half angle, and double angle formulas, but it is unclear what can be done after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\sin {\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2 - \left(\sin {\frac{x}{2}}\right)\left(\sin \left({\frac{x}{2}-2x}\right)\right)=\sin\dfrac x2\left(\sin\dfrac x2-\sin\left(\dfrac x2-2x\right)\right)$$

Now using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas, $\sin\dfrac x2-\sin\left(\dfrac x2-2x\right)=2\sin x\cdot\cos\dfrac x2$

Finally use $\sin x=\sin\left(2\cdot\dfrac x2\right)=?$

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful.